# Guardar valores textarea creados por un *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Estoy creando varios textarea con una pregunta asociada. Ahora necesito guardar esta información para poder guardarla en una BBDD.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<ion-list text-wrap *ngFor="let Quest of navParams.data.question:let i=index">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{Quest.enunciado}}</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea placeholder="Escribe la respuesta"> </ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una función para insertar las preguntas/respuestas en un arreglo a medida que vas modificando, acá te hice un ejemplo:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let question of questions">
     <h3>{{question}}</h3>
     <textarea (blur)="saveResponse(question, $event.target.value)"> </textarea>
  </div>

  <br>
  <h2>Respuestas</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let res of responses">
     <h3>{{res.question}}</h3>
     <h3>{{res.response}}</h3>
  </div>
`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  questions = [ "pregunta 1?", "pregunta 2?", "pregunta 3?", "pregunta 4?"];
  responses = [];

  saveResponse(quest, res) {
    this.responses.push({ question: quest, response: res});
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvu5qp

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación. En cuanto pueda intentaré adaptar el código en mi proyecto. El problema que veo que me va haciendo "push" y me crea un vector infinito de respuestas. Intentaré aprovechar el valor "i" que tengo y solucionarlo.

Comment: Correcto, también podrías verificar si "question" ya existe dentro del arreglo, y en caso de ser así le modificas la respuesta en vez de hacer el push :).

Comment: He podido adaptarlo a mi código sin problemas. Muchas gracias!